# libusb won't install?

Tags: linux, usb, installation, libusb

I am trying to build a program that uses libusb and I get a lot of errors such as

```
i2cbrdg.c:84: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_init’
i2cbrdg.c:88: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_find_busses’
i2cbrdg.c:89: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_find_devices’
i2cbrdg.c:90: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_get_busses’
```

So I am trying to install libusb, but am having troubles doing so. I have installed libusb-dev and that appears to be okay. When I do dpkg -L libusb-dev, I get a list of directories. However, when I dpkg -L libusb, I get

```
Package `libusb' is not installed.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

I have done sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0 and that went okay. When I try to do it again I get the message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-0' for regex 'libusb-1.0'
Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-0-dev' for regex 'libusb-1.0'
libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version.
libusb-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have also tried installing it with yum and it still says that it is not installed. I have downloaded the tar for the package and ran make on that, which also seemed to be okay (no explicit error messages). I don't really know what to try next. The dpkg message just keeps telling me its not installed. Can anyone give me a direction to go in? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should mention what Linux distribution you are using (e.g. Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Debian 6.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries libusb 0.1 and libusb 1.0 are very different.  You should decide now which one you want to use.  I recommend libusb 1.0.  The last time I checked, the `libusb-dev` and `libusb` packages install libusb 0.1, while the `libusb-1.0-0-dev` package should install libusb 1.0, at least in Ubuntu.

After you install the desired library, you will need to `#include` the header file in your C file and also add the right linker option.

For libusb 1.0, the include statement would be

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

and the linker option is

```
-lusb-1.0
```

Comment: I tried to apt-get install the 1.0's and they are already installed and I have that header in already. I did not have the right linker, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: my libusb.h is in /usr/local/include/libusb-1.0...should I change the include directory in the makefile to that instead of just /usr/local/include?

Comment: Well now your problem is that you are calling libusb 0.1 functions.  The libusb 1.0 function names are all prefixed with "libusb_".  Look inside libusb.h to see the names of the functions, and look up the documentation online.  Search for libusb_init.